# ng-content select not working "<element> is not a known element"

Tags: angular, ng-content

I am following [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content#toc-multi-slot-transclusion) like so:

```xml
<div class="app-autocomplete">    
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <div class="app-autocomplete-input">
        <ng-content select="app-autocomplete-input"></ng-content>
      </div>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-icon-button type="button" [disabled]="disabled">
      <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-form-field>

  <!-- ... --> 
</div>
```

But I am getting

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   'app-autocomplete-input' is not a known element:
>
> > 1. If 'app-autocomplete-input' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> > 2. If 'app-autocomplete-input' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
> >                  [ERROR ->]
> >                    
> >                  
> >        ...

and I don't quite understand what the problem is here.

This is how I am trying to use `app-autocomplete`:

```xml
<app-autocomplete>          
  <app-autocomplete-input>
    <input placeholder="Yo"/>
  </app-autocomplete-input>          
</app-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Have you made sure that the `app-autocomplete-input` component is added to the module that your last template is declared in (where you are using the `<app-autocomplete-input>` tag)?

Comment: Have you read the error message? Is app-autocomplete-input an Angular component or not? If it is, is it declared in the module? If it's not, is it a web component? If none of the above, then you can't use app-autocomplete-input, since it's neither a standard DOM element, nor an angular component, nor a web component.

Comment: @JBNizet No. It's not a component.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel It's not a component. I just tried to inject content using a named `ng-content` element.

Comment: Then you can't use that. Use a div, or a span, or any other standard dom element.

Comment: @JBNizet Hm, so how does the tutorial do it then? I must have overlooked something then. I thought that's just a nice way to place content in a more convenient way from outside of a component.

Comment: They state exactly this scenario in the part right before the section you linked to... "However, you will hit an error if you use the <card-body> tag now. Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: 'card-body' is not a known element

Angular 2 does not recognize the card-body tag. card-body is neither a directive nor a component. A quick way to get around this error is to add schema metadata property in your module, set value to NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA in your module file."

Comment: I would not recommend doing that though and instead would use DOM nodes as @JBNizet mentioned

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel Ok I think I have to rethink that whole thing. I need an `input` element inside that `mat-form-field`. The problem I have is that I also need `formControlName` to be set from outside since this element may be part of a `form` ..

Comment: You can still do what you are doing, just change it from `<app-autocomplete-input><input placeholder="Yo"/></app-autocomplete-input>` to `<ng-container class="app-autocomplete-input"><input placeholder="Yo"/></ng-container>` and then just change your `select` to look for a class instead of a DOM node (i.e. `select=".app-autocomplete-input"`)

Comment: If you want only project one thing, you don't even need anything wrapping your input, and you can just use ng-content, without any select attribute. As explained in the tutorial you linked to: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content#toc-basic-transclusion-single-slot-

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel Okay - this kind of works but it also seems to break the material input. The placeholder gets displayed wrong etc. I guess I can't do that the way I intend it to do or I have another mistake somwhere

Comment: @JBNizet Yeah, I know. I just intended to insert further content later on which is why intended to use `select` but thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel And there it is. It was another error on my side. The solution you proposed works - thank you!

Comment: @JBNizet and thanks to you too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ### Objective

The actual objective of your is to leverage `Content Projection` to customize the component further while using.

> ### Issue

The main issue is to use custom component `app-autocomplete-input` which is not provided anywhere.

> ### Fix

Since you don't have custom component and never intended to have custom component. You use simple html tag like `div` `span` or you can use css class ex `autocomplete-input`.

> #### Modified code

```xml
<div class="app-autocomplete">    
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <div class="app-autocomplete-input">
        <ng-content select=".app-autocomplete-input"></ng-content>
      </div>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-icon-button type="button" [disabled]="disabled">
      <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-form-field>

  <!-- ... --> 
</div>
```

### app-autocomplete.html

```xml
<app-autocomplete>          
  <div class="app-autocomplete-input">
    <input placeholder="Yo"/>
  </div>          
</app-autocomplete>
```